# How to sign the transaction using Geth in android

Tags: go-ethereum, android

I'm using Geth.aar library for handling ethereum.

I generated the address, gas price, gas estimation, and transaction count.

now I want to sign the transaction.

Please help who knows the answer.

Comment: I am compiling `geth` sources into shared library and calling functions in this library from C++, this is how  my Ethereum Wallet signs transactions in Android. But this is a bit complicated, you may probably go for running a Javascript implementation in some browser engine or use Java API.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to sign a transaction from your Android application?

For this you can use the Java library Web3j https://web3j.io
It simplifies the process of interacting with nodes from applications

Comment: I'm using Geth.aar library.

Comment: If I understand correctly, geth.arr is the implementation of the go-ethereum node for Android.

Therefore, I see a scheme of interaction with the Ethereum network:
Your app -> Web3j -> Geth

Comment: I'm not using Web3j but I'm using android version of go ethereum i.e Geth.aar